# How To Have Modular Dependency Registration in Different Projects in Bit-Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, bit, bit-framework

I have many projects in a solution that use bit-framework. I need to register Interfaces in each projects, and have Modular Registration. How can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imaging you've following modules: "FrontApp + SubSys1 + SubSys2"

AppStartup is as it was before with two modifications:

1- Add following code after `AssemblyContainer.Current.Init();`:

```
AssemblyContainer.Current.AddAppAssemblies(typeof(SubSys1AppModule).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, typeof(SubSys2AppModule).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

2- Change GetAppModules's  body  to following:

```
public IEnumerable<IAppModule> GetAppModules()
{
    yield return this;
    yield return new SubSys1AppModule();
    yield return new SubSys2AppModule();
}
```

SubSys1AppModule's codes:

```
public class SubSys1AppModule : IAspNetCoreAppModule // It's possible in owin based apps by implementing IOwinAppModule
{
    public virtual void ConfigureDependencies(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IServiceCollection services, IDependencyManager dependencyManager)
    {
        dependencyManager.Register<Module1Contract, Module1Implementation>();
    }
}
```